# About setTimeout/Interval context

Tags: javascript, call, settimeout

Why I can't do this:

```
function f(){console.log(this)}
f.call(this);
setInterval(f.call, 1000, this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.bind` instead of `.call`:

```
function f(){console.log(this)}
setInterval(f.bind(the_context_obj), 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setInterval(f.call.bind(f, this), 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qx3jU/

It's just a bad way of saying     `setInterval(f.bind(this), 1000);` though

Comment: Why not just `f.bind(this)` ?

Comment: @xdazz to be honest, I just looked at `f.call` and took the path of least thinking. That's much better indeed :D

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing the *value of* `f.call` so you lose the association with `f`.

Answer (score 0):

[From Mozilla Dev page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Syntax is :

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer. If you want to enable this functionality on that browser you must use a compatibility code (see the [Callback arguments paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval#Callback_arguments)).

Then I'll recommend you to use an anonymous function like this

```
var x = this;
setInterval( function() { f.call(x); }, 1000 );
```

Hope this helps.